# Why does locate give an incorrect path?

Tags: linux, centos

I was just trying to find a file on my test webserver so I ran "locate foo.conf" and it told me it was in /usr/lib.  But then when I went to /usr/lib, I couldn't find the file.

So I tried running "ls $(locate foo.conf)" and it told me that the file didn't exist.  Does anybody know why this would happen?

Comment: Have you tried running a database update: "updatedb" and see if the file still exists?

Comment: What was the purpose of switching from `locate foo.conf` to $(locate foo.conf) ?

Comment: thepocketwise: The backticks were not showing up, as they don't in your comment, at least in my browser ...

Comment: $() is much preferred over backticks, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Dennis: Everyone serious about bash should read that FAQ, the Pitfalls, and the Guide of that wiki :-)  Greycat knows his stuff :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

locate uses a database generated and updated by the updatedb command that is run by cron ( usually every night).  So it is possible your database is out of date.  Try the following and then run the locate command again:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Comment: Sure enough, it doesn't find the file anymore.